# what do I need to use XSLT 2.0 with Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, xslt-2.0

what do I need to use XSLT 2.0 with Delphi(win32)? At the moment I use MSXML6 for all my xml transformation. But MSXML6 has no support for XSLT 2.0.

**The solution** (by [ErvinS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103347/ervins))
Using the AltovaXML library. After installation you have to import the AltovXML typelibrary. Then you can use a source like this:

```
procedure TfrmMainAltovaXmlDemo.btnTransformClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  xmlApp: AltovaXMLLib_TLB.Application;
  xslt2: AltovaXMLLib_TLB.XSLT2;
begin
  xmlApp := AltovaXMLLib_TLB.CoApplication.Create;
  xslt2 := xmlApp.XSLT2;
  xslt2.InputXMLFromText := FInputXml;
  xslt2.XSLFromText := FXslSource;
  FOutputXML := xslt2.ExecuteAndGetResultAsString;
end;
```

Comment: see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982687/how-do-i-display-xml-using-an-xslt-document-in-a-delphi-app and this German answer:  http://www.delphipraxis.net/153477-delphi-win32-und-xslt-2-0-a.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Altova](http://www.altova.com) has [AltovaXML](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html), which is a free COM based component.

Comment: +1; now that is cool! I have updated http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altova#Products and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_template_engine#Implementations
Thanks!

Comment: @Alejandro: note that .NET can often be called as COM as well. Also note that COM usually is not my favourite means of integrating a 3rd party piece into my Delphi app.

Comment: @Jeroen Pluimers: You are right. But allow people wich has not .Net platform aviable (or Java as well) to update to XSLT 2.0 is great, because I think we will wait MS for very long time...

Comment: @Jeroen: I'm not very fond of COM too, but Heinz specified that he is using MSXML. I personally use DIXml, but it doesn't support XSLT 2.0 yet.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no XSLT 2.0 implmenentation for Delphi itself.
In general, there are only a few XSLT 2.0 implementations around.
Wikipedia has an [overview of XSLT processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT_processor).

- [SAXON](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) has an open source implementation of XSLT 2.0 in Java and .NET.
- [XJR](https://www.p6r.com/software/xjr.html) is a paid implementation in C/C++.

You can integrate all of them in your Delphi apps.
Depending on how close you want to have such an integration, there are a few starting points:

- Java is closest to integrate [using JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997495/using-a-java-class-from-delphi) or [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).
- .NET can be integrated using [JCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048540/hosting-clr-in-delphi-with-jcl-example), [COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460486/using-net-classes-through-com-objects-in-delphi-sometimes-hangs), [Unmanaged Exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140656/how-to-use-unmanaged-exports-in-delphi), [Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hy), inverse P/Invoke.
- XJR can likely be integrated as a DLL

--jeroen